# XSD 1.1 Assert : Compare an element value to Sum of list's element attribute

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

Can someone help me understand how I can achieve and enforce the validation in my XSD.

FieldDetails.length value should always be equal to SubFieldSet's SubFieldDetail.length value.
As per schema SubFieldDetail is a list. So I need to assert and ensure that when the list of values are constructed their overall length does not exceed "FieldDetails.length" value

```
<xs:element name="FieldDefinitionDetails">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="FieldDefinition" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="FieldDefinition">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="FieldDetails"/>
            <xs:element ref="SubFieldSet" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="sum(SubFieldSet/SubFieldDetail/@length) eq FieldDetails/@length"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="SubFieldSet">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="SubFieldDetail" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="FieldDetails">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="LengthType" type="lengthType" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="binary" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="mask" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="hasSubField" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="SubFieldDetail">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:simpleType name="lengthType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Fixed"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Embedded"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Example ( XSD validation should throw error for below scenario). SubFieldSet is always dynamic.

FieldDetails value is 6 where as the SubFieldDetail's value is > 6.

```
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="2" length="2" name="DE 2" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="true"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="3" length="6" name="DE 3" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
    <SubFieldSet>
        <SubFieldDetail id="1" length="2" name="Transaction Type"/>
        <SubFieldDetail id="2" length="34" name="From Account Type"/>
        <SubFieldDetail id="3" length="2" name="To Account Type"/>
    </SubFieldSet>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="4" length="12" name="DE 4" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="5" length="12" name="DE 5" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="6" length="12" name="DE 6" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="9" length="8" name="DE 9" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="10" length="8" name="DE 10" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="12" length="12" name="DE 12" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="14" length="4" name="DE 14" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="22" length="12" name="DE 22" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="23" length="3" name="DE 23" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="24" length="3" name="DE 24" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="25" length="4" name="DE 25" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="26" length="4" name="DE 26" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="30" length="24" name="DE 30" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="31" length="2" name="DE 31" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="32" length="2" name="DE 32" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="33" length="2" name="DE 33" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="37" length="12" name="DE 37" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="38" length="6" name="DE 38" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="40" length="3" name="DE 40" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="41" length="8" name="DE 41" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="42" length="15" name="DE 42" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="43" length="2" name="DE 43" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="48" length="3" name="DE 48" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="49" length="3" name="DE 49" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="50" length="3" name="DE 50" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="51" length="3" name="DE 51" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="54" length="3" name="DE 54" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="55" length="3" name="DE 55" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="62" length="3" name="DE 62" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="63" length="3" name="DE 63" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="71" length="8" name="DE 71" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="72" length="3" name="DE 72" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="73" length="6" name="DE 73" LengthType="Fixed" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="93" length="2" name="DE 93" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="94" length="2" name="DE 94" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="95" length="2" name="DE 95" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="100" length="2" name="DE 100" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="111" length="3" name="DE 111" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="123" length="3" name="DE 123" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="124" length="3" name="DE 124" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="125" length="3" name="DE 125" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails id="127" length="3" name="DE 127" LengthType="Embedded" binary="false" mask="false"/>
</FieldDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath uses `/` and `@` e.g. `<xs:assert test="sum(SubFieldSet/SubFieldDetail/@length) eq FieldDetails/@length"/>`.

But

```
<xs:element name="FieldDetails">
    <xs:complexType>           
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>       
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

should be

```
<xs:element name="FieldDetails">
    <xs:complexType>           
        <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>       
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

for the paths to make sense:

```
<xs:element name="FieldDefinition">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="FieldDetails"/>
            <xs:element ref="SubFieldSet" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="sum(SubFieldSet/SubFieldDetail/@length) eq FieldDetails/@length"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Complete example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FieldDefinition>
    <FieldDetails length="6"/>
    <SubFieldSet>
        <SubFieldDetail length="2"/>
        <SubFieldDetail length="4"/>
        <SubFieldDetail length="4"/>
    </SubFieldSet>
</FieldDefinition>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" vc:minVersion="1.1"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning">
    <xs:element name="FieldDefinition">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="FieldDetails"/>
                <xs:element ref="SubFieldSet" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="sum(SubFieldSet/SubFieldDetail/@length) eq FieldDetails/@length"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="SubFieldSet">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="SubFieldDetail" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="FieldDetails">
        <xs:complexType>           
            <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>       
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="SubFieldDetail">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>
```

gives `Assertion evaluation ('sum(SubFieldSet/SubFieldDetail/@length) eq FieldDetails/@length') for element 'FieldDefinition' on schema type '#AnonType_FieldDefinition' did not succeed.`

Comment: where exactly should I place the assertion ?

Comment: @Balaji, see whether the edit helps.

Comment: I did  the same thing already but its not validating. I also have few other attributes in "SubFieldDetail" and "FieldDetails" but that should not matter right?

Comment: @Balaji, I have added a minimal but complete example together with the validation error that Xerces gives. Don't know where your attempt fails, perhaps, if the minimal but complete example doesn't help to fix yours, start a new question where you show all necessary but minimal and complete details of XML input, XSD schema, validator software to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maritn question is updated now with as is details I am trying to validate. Can you please check now. Its complete

Comment: Please state which validating parser you use, which errors you get and which ones you expect instead.

Comment: @Balaji, and obviously the assertion `<xs:assert test="sum(SubFieldSet/SubFieldDetail/@length) eq FieldDetails/@length"/>` doesn't make much sense on all those elements that no `SubFieldSet` at all but specify a value greater than 0 in the `length` attribute of `FieldDetails`, unless you want to report an assertion violation for all those cases.